# how do sort custom list in product view?

Tags: magento2, blocks, cache, sorting

I have custom module in product_view.
in customBlock so i want sort list by helpfulless or date.
how do it?

[image]

> Note:  i used ajax post to Customblock.php when change sortby. if
>   refresh cache before change select it post value to Customblock.php.
>   if don't  refresh cache and change select it not run Customblock.php.

So any suggestion to i can sort custom list? thanks so muck.

Comment: There is a way to [disable a cache type](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-en) using the CLI. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why you want to load a newly generated block every time. That will normally be very resource consuming once you start seeing your traffic increase. It can even crash your system. Such a change will imply rebuilding your block and thus assembling the full page with all the cached blocks again every time a user hits your page.

I am guessing all you want to do is change one value for every user. My suggestion is you add an AJAX call to the web API and change it dynamically using AngularJs or jQuery whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Or explain more in detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: yes in product view i have some product question. i wat sort it with some condition. I use ajax post. Any suggestion? @awavi.

Comment: I dont understand very well what you are trying to do

Comment: I edited question